# How to display output as numbered list

Tags: c#

I was wondering how I would go about displaying user input as a numbered list? e.g.

1. Jam
2. Tea
3. Something
4. Something else

This is what I have so far in regards to setting up the array and sorting alphabetically but want to also display as per above and can't find any information on this anywhere. Thanks in advance.

```
//call method to sort array in alphabetical order
        fillArraySort();

        //call method to display in numbered list
        //displayNumberedList();

    }

    /*declare the array
    ask user for index (size of array) and store user input array*/

    static void fillArraySort()
    {
        int a;
        Console.WriteLine("How many inanimate object names do you wish to enter?");
        a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] index = new int[a];
        for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name of object:");
            index [i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Array.Sort(index);
        Console.WriteLine("The array sorted in alphabetical order is: ");
        foreach (var i in index)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    //static void displayNumberedList()
    //{
        //code
```

Comment: To start with, I suggest that if you want to sort a list of names you use a `string` array and not an `int` array.

Comment: All you have in the code is an int array which you are already sorting. You want us to suggest how to take string input from user?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion re the string array @Deolus. I will change it to string instead of int.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I will change the datatype to string. I was going to then sort alphabetically, and display the output with the number beside it instead of just House, Kay, Car, something, that it will display it as a numbered list (similar to bullet points). Sorry for not explaining too well. Thank you.

Comment: You are converting use entered values in to int. You need to take item names from the user and store them in the string array. Then sort that array. And while displaying you can display the number in front of the item names. You need to use for loop for that. `Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1}", i + 1, index[I]);`

Comment: Thank you for the break down, it is clearer in my mind now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void FillArraySort()
{
    Console.WriteLine("How many inanimate object names do you wish to enter?");

    int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    var array  = new string[number];

    for (int index = 0; index < number; index++)
    {
        var message = string.Format("Enter name of object {0}:", index + 1);

        Console.WriteLine(message);

        array[index] = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    Array.Sort(array);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("The array sorted in alphabetical order is:");

    for (int index = 0; index < number; index++)
    {
        var item    = array[index];

        var message = string.Format("{0}. {1}", index + 1, item);

        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. I'll have a read through and break it down into more than one method. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string[] items = new string[]
{
    "Jam", "Tea", "Something", "Something else"
};

Console.WriteLine(
    String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine,
        items.Select((x, n) => $"{n + 1}. {x}")));
```

That gives:

```
1. Jam
2. Tea
3. Something
4. Something else
```